# plotting values calculated in loop

Tags: matlab, loops

Here I'm trying to plot the error (normalized difference between matrices) against the  variable rho. All other variables should remain constant.
What I'd really like to do is store rho as a separate vector and store values for the error as they're being calculated in each loop.

Any ideas?

```
%Variables:
%MatrixGen.m:   p,q - matrix size, rho- percentage complete, r - rank
%NuclearNorm.m :   Zincomplete

clear

p=10; q=10;
r=2;

for rho=0.1:0.3:0.9;

    [Ztrue, Zincomplete] = MatrixGen(p,q,r,rho)

    tic
    [Zreconstructed] = NuclearNorm(Zincomplete)
    toc

    Error= norm(Ztrue-Zreconstructed, 'fro')

    hold on
    plot (rho, Error)

end
```

Answer (score 1):

'Is that what you meant?

```
%Variables:
%MatrixGen.m:   p,q - matrix size, rho- percentage complete, r - rank
%NuclearNorm.m :   Zincomplete

clear
p=10; q=10;
r=2;

rho = 0.1:0.3:0.9
errors = zeros(size(rho))

for i=1:length(rho);

    [Ztrue, Zincomplete] = MatrixGen(p,q,r,rho(i))

    tic
    [Zreconstructed] = NuclearNorm(Zincomplete)
    toc

    errors(i) = norm(Ztrue-Zreconstructed, 'fro')
end

plot(rho, errors)

end
```